# laravel unknown column in sql Query

Tags: sql, laravel-4

Unknown column 'erp_purchase_order_details.received' in 'having clause'.column is present in table but it shows the above error

code:

```
$status_result = DB::table('erp_purchase_order_details')->select(DB::raw('COUNT(erp_purchase_order_details.product_category_id) as count_products'),DB::raw('COUNT(erp_purchase_order_details.received) as count_received'))
        ->havingRaw('erp_purchase_order_details.received > 1')
        ->where('erp_purchase_order_details.purchase_order_id','=',$purchase_order_id)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `HAVING` clause condition you should use only aggregation function, instead you have:

```
->havingRaw('erp_purchase_order_details.received > 1')
```

If the condition is about the column, move it to the `WHERE` clause, otherwise use the appropriate aggregation function, like `COUNT`, etc.